# Joining Two Rows

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table

id       |  data_txt   |   itemid 
1         |   aaa             |   1
2    |    bbb           |   1

In this case i am taking input data_txt and I want to get the itemid How can I do this? suppose i am getting aaa & bbb and from that I want 1

Comment: I think you should first read a short introduction into MySQL: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemid FROM KindOfTable WHERE data_txt IN('aaa', 'bbb');
SELECT itemid FROM KindOfTable WHERE data_txt = 'aaa' OR data_txt = 'bbb';
```

This is a very elementary SELECT statement; you really need to read some basic textbook on SQL queries.